# How to change the color of one specific letter on a web page (wrap the text)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, greasemonkey, word-wrap

I want to change one letter, let's call it "n", to a different color, let's say yellow. I want this done on all pages and in all fonts and sizes.

I have found [this script](http://greasemonkey.win-start.de/casestudy/dumbquotes.html) for Greasemonkey, which I think can be modified to do what I want.

I have tried replacing the letter "n" with `"<p style="color:#FFB90F">n</p>"`, to no avail. It just gets inserted into the page without being evaluated as CSS.

How can I do this? I would like the ability to specify a list of letters and colors.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common-ish problem, and beware of answers that use `.innerHTML` or `.html()`.  These will bust the page's HTML (replacing parts of tags with invalid strings), and/or orphan Event handlers that may be required for the page's function.

A robust solution will use DOM techniques to modify only text nodes.

The following **complete script** uses the standard-ish `wrapTextWithElement()` function.
You can see the code in action at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jpmdK/).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Wrapping/Coloring letters in an HTML page
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

//-- Use CSS, *not* inline styles to color/style things
GM_addStyle ( "                                 \
    span.coloredLetter {                        \
        background: yellow;                     \
    }                                           \
" );

var letI_Wrapper    = new wrapTextWithElement ('i', '<span class="coloredLetter">');
letI_Wrapper.wrap (document.body); // Here we wrap everything.

function wrapTextWithElement (targText, elemToWrapWith, bCaseSensitive) {
    var self            = this;
    var bCaseSensitive  = bCaseSensitive || false;
    self.targRegEx      = new RegExp ("(" + targText + ")", bCaseSensitive ? "" : "i");
    self.elemToWrapWith = elemToWrapWith;

    self.wrap = function (node) {
        $(node).contents ().each ( function () {
            if (this.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                self.wrap (this);
            }
            else if (this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                var ndText  = this.nodeValue;

                if (self.targRegEx.test (ndText) ) {
                    var replaceNodes = $.map (
                        ndText.split (self.targRegEx),
                        function (phrase) {
                            if (self.targRegEx.test (phrase) ) {
                                /*  The $(HTML, props) form does not work if the HTML
                                    has attributes
                                var wrapped = $(self.elemToWrapWith, {text: phrase} );
                                */
                                var wrapped = $(self.elemToWrapWith).text (phrase);

                                return wrapped.get ();
                            }
                            else {
                                if (phrase == "")
                                    return null;
                                else
                                    return document.createTextNode (phrase)
                            }
                        }
                    );
                    $(this).replaceWith (replaceNodes);
                }
            }
        } );
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not exactly your problem, but maybe it helps you http://letteringjs.com/. There are every letter in a own `span` with a class.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery and try something like this:

```
$('p:contains(n)').each(function() {
   $(this).html(
      $(this).html().replace('n', '<span style="color:#F00;">n</span>')
   );
});
```

This just finds the letter "n" in any p tags, so you would need to adjust to fit your needs.

`#F00` represents the color `red` in hexidecimal

Comment: This is bad.  It will bust the page: `<span>` becomes `<spa<span style="color:#F00;">n</span>>`; javascript for buttons, links, etc. will be trashed; etc.